# Visual Studio 2019 v16.11 update failed: Access is denied

Tags: visual-studio-2019, access-denied

Our VS 2019 update to v16.11 failed, and now this VS install is unusable.  All projects report 'Unloaded' when they are opened.

This is only affecting the server installation.  In my Amazon Workspace environment, the update was successful and I can open/build/debug the projects with no problems.

We've attempted to repair, modify and uninstall/reinstall VS 2019 but an 'Access is Denied' error is encountered for each.

We are running all as Admin, my account is a machine admin.

I've found no 'Known Issues' related to this, but the update was just released on 8/10/2021.

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Answer (score 1):

We resolved the issue by logging in to the server as a 'Local Administrator' and performing the update.  Worked like a charm!